# Get value from input in function that not in $(document).ready(JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JS script file.

In this file I have code that populate inputs with value from calendar

Here is code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

columnSettings = $('#visibleColumns').val();

SetColumnCheckboxes();

$('#tableDetails').DataTable({
    'columnDefs': columnDefs,
    'sDom': '<"table-options"<"top length"l><"top paging"p><"top filtering"f>>rt<"bottom"i>',
    'sScrollY': '1px',
    'scrollX': true,
    'autoWidth': true,
    'lengthMenu': [[-1, 10, 25, 50, 100], [dictionary.find('all'), 10, 25, 50, 100]],
    'language': dataTablesLanguage
});

//cultureTwoLetterName is a global variable from the view that contains the two letter iso language name
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[cultureTwoLetterName]);

$('#calendar').weekMonthDatepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    weekHeader: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>',
    minDate: -loggingRetention,
    maxDate: '+0D',
    weekSelection: true,
    weekSelected: SelectionCallback,
    monthSelection: true,
    monthSelected: SelectionCallback
});

$('#startDate').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: -loggingRetention,
    maxDate: '+0D'
});


$('#endDate').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: -loggingRetention,
    maxDate: '+0D'
});

$('#selectGroups').on('change', function () {
    PopulateSelectVehicles();
});

$('#selectVehicles').on('change', function () {
    var imei = $(this).val();
    var device = getDevice(imei);
    configureReportpageForDevice(device);

    var start = $('#calendar').weekMonthDatepicker('getStartDate');
    var stop = $('#calendar').weekMonthDatepicker('getEndDate');
    var ui;

    if (start != null && stop != null) {
        var ui = { 'startDate': start, 'endDate': stop };
    }

    PopulateTableDetails(null, ui);
});

$('#calendar').on('change', function () {
    $('#startDate').val(moment($(this).val()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    $('#endDate').val(moment($(this).val()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    startdate = $('#startDate').val();
    end = $('#endDate').val();
    alert(end);
    var start = $('#calendar').weekMonthDatepicker('getStartDate');
    var stop = $('#calendar').weekMonthDatepicker('getEndDate');
    var ui;
    if (start != null && stop != null) {
        ui = { 'startDate': start, 'endDate': stop };

    }

    PopulateTableDetails(null, ui);
});

$('#startDate').on('change', function () {
    $(this).val(moment($(this).val()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));

    if ($('#endDate').val() == '' || moment($('#endDate').val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY') < moment($(this).val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY')) { //endDate niet ingevuld of < startDate --> endDate = startDate
        $('#endDate').val($(this).val());
    }

    var start = moment($(this).val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY');
    var stop = moment($('#endDate').val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY');

    var ui = { 'startDate': start, 'endDate': stop };

    PopulateTableDetails(null, ui);
});

$('#endDate').on('change', function () {
    $(this).val(moment($(this).val()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));

    if ($('#startDate').val() == '' || moment($('#startDate').val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY') > moment($(this).val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY')) { //startDate niet ingevuld of > endDate --> startDate = endDate
        $('#startDate').val($(this).val());
    }

    var start = moment($('#startDate').val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY');
    var stop = moment($(this).val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY');
    var ui = { 'startDate': start, 'endDate': stop };

    PopulateTableDetails(null, ui);
});
```

});

I need to get values from `startDate` and `endDate`

I can do it writing `startdate = $('#startDate').val();` in `$('#calendar').on('change', function () {` function.

But I have function out of `document.ready` block, that connected with map and cannot be used in `document.ready` block.

Here is code of this function

```
function getDriving() {
var startdatevalue = startdate;
alert(startdatevalue);
var url = $('#map').data('request-url2');
$.getJSON(url,
    function (data) {
        var marker = [];

        $.each(data,
            function (i, item) {
                marker.push({
                    'location': new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude),
                    'map': map,
                    'weight': item.Speed,
                    'radius': 10
                });
            });
        var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(marker);

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray
        });
        heatmap.setMap(map);
    });
```

};

And when I write  `var startdatevalue = startdate;
alert(startdatevalue);` in it it is null.

How I can get value in this function correctly?

Here is full code of js [Code](https://pastebin.com/i07YbRPM)

I tried to write `initMap` and other related functions in `document.ready`, but I get `initMap not a function` error. Because of this line in View `<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCea6m‌​L2cqwVid2ESIjuJ0C31R‌​bNVQNPY0&libraries=v‌​isualization&callbac‌​k=initMap"> </script>`

Thank's for help

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. It's all about scope. Any var's you cast in the .ready event are only available in that scope (function).

So the work-around is to cast the var outside that function. (global scope)

If you have other modules/functions that need to read these vars your best bet is make your own app object and set the vars in that, you can then read those vars elsewhere in your app code.

```
  var app  = {};

    ..

    $(document).ready(function () {

    app.startdate = //some value

    ..

    });
```

Now anywhere else in your app you can access that global object

```
console.log(app.startdate)
```

I have used a global object as you may need to have start, end date and other vars that can be accessed by the outside modules

You can just do

```
var startdate
```

Outside the ready function and that will also work.

- The problem with this design method is that the var may not be set when the 2nd functions requests it.

This problem is solved by either passing the var in directly to the other function. Or using an event drive system, where by function 2 subscribes to an event on function 1 that passes the var as it is set, or changed.

Comment: I tried this, but it seems problem not in this. I will edit my post with full js file code.

I think problem in that function calls before input is populated

Comment: I tried to write initMap and other related functions in `document.ready`, but I get `initMap not a function` error. Because of this line in View 

`<script async
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCea6mL2cqwVid2ESIjuJ0C31RbNVQNPY0&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
</script>`

Comment: Well this is not the ideal way of doing things. If you need to pass a var to another function the best bet is pass it directly, or use and event driven system whereby the your function is subscribing to an event so that when the var is set it triggers.

Comment: I posted all js code in my question.  

`https://pastebin.com/i07YbRPM`

Comment: The problem is the app design. SetVehicles can't function without the user selecting a date in your drop down. So the problem is not caused by the code itself its caused by the lack of user input. You need to adjust the UI so the user first sets the date - then once that happens the setVehicles function can be called (passing in the dates). Otherwise pre-set the dates on init to todays date for example then if the user sets a custom date re-call setVehicles with the dates from the click event.